# Is there a way to enter a string starting with '-' sign as a command line argument using the argparse module? (without using flags)

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, argparse

so i have this code

```
# driver code    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # parse command line arguments 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("InputDataFile", help="Enter the name of CSV file with .csv extention",type=str)
    parser.add_argument("Weights", nargs=1, help="Enter the weight vector comma separated" ,type=str)
    parser.add_argument("Impacts", nargs=1, help="Enter the impact vector comma separated",type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()


    main(vars(args))
```

and i want to enter a string like

```
python top2.py data.csv "0,1,1,1" "-,+,+,+"
```

but I get input error :

```
usage: top2.py [-h] InputDataFile Weights Impacts
top2.py: error: the following arguments are required: Impacts
```

the code works properly if the first character for input string is '+' sign, with a '-' anywhere in-between (as in "+,-,+"). But if first char is '-' i get the above error.
what i am guessing is that the parser takes the '-' hyphen as the beginning of another flag and its arguments.

I couldnt find any relevant material online, please help.

And it is important to input the string in the manner given above, so cannot change the input format.

edit: if i enter the string as "- ,+,+,+" or add spaces anywhere in the string, he code runs fine.

Comment: If it's that simple, without other arguments that use `argarse` features, you might just want to parse `sys.argv` directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a lone `--` to your command line to indicate "this is the end of options", like this:

```
python top2.py -- data.csv "0,1,1,1" "-,+,+,+"
```

Everything after the `--` is parsed as a positional argument rather than an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around for the time being...

argparse provides us the facility to customize the prefix character.
We can do this

```
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='/')
```

and instead of the default hyphen sign, all our flags/optional arguments can now be accessed by using '/'.
for example for help, use this

```
python top2.py /h
```

part of output:

```
optional arguments:
  /h, //help     show this help message and exit
```

Comment: This might be acceptable if your target platform is exclusively Windows (or VMS if my memory serves correctly) but will be very confusing on Unix-like platforms.